# Parameter won't work outside of $() - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple AJAX script and I am curious why the parameter won't work outside `$()` block:

```
var loadWork = function(el) { //element which href will be used
    var url = $(el).attr('href'); //it doesn't work if 'el' is not in $()
    $.get(url, function(data) {
        $('#work-gallery').html(data);
    });

}

$(document).ready(function() {
    loadWork('#work ul li a[href="includes/wdes.html"]')
    $('#work ul li a').click(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var element = $(this);
        loadWork(element);
    });
});
```

That `el` (short for element) parameter of the `loadWork` function needs to be inside `$()` in `*var url = ...*` expression. Why is that, when I pass it as either a variable or literal element in function call?

Comment: Because it needs to be in $() for it to work? Why do you not want to use it?

Comment: because `el` is a string.

Comment: Your question effectively is *"Why do DOM elements no behave like jQuery objects?"* and the answer is "Because they aren't."

Comment: This question be like "Why do we not eat with our nose?"..

Comment: @Tomalak this is not the question, the second case is already a jQuery Object

Comment: Try to put together a JsFiddle or SO snippet that reproduces the problem. It seems like your code should totally work...

Comment: @RonenCypis I suspect you have seen the `$(this)` being passed to `loadWork` via `element`, and overlooked the first call to `loadWork` that is being passed a string, as I did to start with :)

Comment: @JamesThorpe Correct!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are passing a string, so if you would not wrap it by  `$()` it will just be a string, so would be similiar to

```
'#work ul li a[href="includes/wdes.html"]'.attr('xyz')
```

but thats nonsense as the .attr method is a property of jqueryObjects, so using

```
$('#work ul li a[href="includes/wdes.html"]')
```

will select the matching domnodes and wrap them as jquery Object so you can run jquery methods like .attr()

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do:

"*On clicking a a link inside `#work`, load whatever the `href` of that link returns into `#work-gallery`.*"

For simple content loading jobs, there is the [`.load()` jQuery function](http://api.jquery.com/load/), which takes a URL and puts the returned HTML inside an element – just what you are doing in your `loadWork()` function. So let's scratch that function, it's superfluous.

Second, you want to load something initially. It's easiest to simply trigger the click event on one of the links, since we already have the proper click handler.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#work a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#work-gallery').load(this.href);
    }).first().click();
});
```

Note how `this` inside the event handler points to the DOM object, so you can use `this.href` directly instead of taking the detour of calling `.attr('href')`.